# Expectation of maximum of two random variables inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation

I have a question about the expectation of maximum of two variables.

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, and $Y$ be random variables.

Suppose $E[X_1] > E[X_2]$.
Then is it necessarily the case that
$E[\max(X_1, Y)] > E[\max(X_2, Y)]$?

If there is any assumption that has to be made, please let me know.

Comment: @Astyx Thank you very much. By the way, can you explain a little bit more in detail? Sketch of the proof will be greatly helpful to me!

Comment: Let us try what happen if $Y=X_1$? Then we have $E(X_1)\geqslant E(\max(X_1, X_2))\geqslant \max(EX_1, EX_2)=EX_1$. This follows $\max(X_1, X_2) =X_1$ a.s., i.e. $X_2 \leqslant X_1$ a.s. So, if we construct $X_1, X_2$ such that $EX_1 > EX_2$ and $X_2 \nleqslant X_1$ a.s. then we get a contradiction. I thing we need an extra condition.

Comment: @SKHong: Are $X_1, X_2$, and $Y$ supposed to be independent?

Comment: @Michael Lugo  Ok. Let us suppose that they are independent.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Here's a counterexample.  Consider the following three independent random variables:

- let $X_1$ be a constant-valued random variable, which is always 1.
- let $X_2$ be 3 with probability $1/4$ and 0 otherwise.
- let $Y$ be 1 with probability $1/2$ and 0 otherwise.

Then $E(X_1) = 1, E(X_2) = 3/4$.

But since $X_1 \ge Y$, we have $\max(X_1, Y) = X_1$ and so $E(\max(X_1, Y)) = 1$.  But $\max(X_2, Y)$ is 3 with probability $1/4$, 1 with probability $3/8$ and 0 otherwise, so $E(\max(X_2, Y))= 9/8$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Which assumption sholud be made to guarantee the second inequality? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't know.  I constructed this counterexample by trying to make $X_1$ have a "narrow" distribution and make $X_2$ have a "wide" distribution, so maybe some assumption on the range or on the second moments?